Can two conformal mappings be combined?
A conformal mapping function ${z_1} = {\omega _{\rm{1}}}(\zeta )$ within a complex domain maps the unit circle in the $\zeta$-plane to the $z_1$-plane. Similarly, there is another function ${z_2} = {\omega _{\rm{2}}}(\zeta )$. Combining $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$, we can obtain ${z_3} = {\omega _1}({\omega _2}(\zeta ))$.
Can this function also satisfy conformal mapping, and are there any applicable conditions for it to do so?
The following figure is an attempt I made. If feasible, can any smooth and simply connected region be combined with $\omega_{\rm{1}}$ for conformal mapping?

